# React Navigation: Force screen to animate from left to right

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

With React Navigation v6.x and using the `.navigate()` function, new views always animate from right to left.

Typically this is fine, but I have a couple views that I always want to load from the left.

I have tried to read the docs, code examples, and stackoverflow threads related to transitions and I cannot glean any useful information.

Can anyone can give me some pointers on this?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

**First make this below.**

```
 const leftToRightAnimation = {
  cardStyleInterpolator: ({ current, layouts }) => {
    return {
      cardStyle: {
        transform: [
          {
            translateX: current.progress.interpolate({
              inputRange: [0, 1],
              outputRange: [-layouts.screen.width, 0],
            }),
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
};
```

Basically all it's doing is it's moving the screen from the x direction of full screen width away in left direction to fitting the screen. And implicitly progress is going from 0 to 1.

- The `transform` works just like any other react-native component read more here (https://reactnative.dev/docs/transforms).
- And it uses interpolate from the react-native `animated` (https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated)

**Then put it in the screen you want the transition to apply to.**

```
<NavigationContainer>
      <Root.Navigator headerMode="none" initialRouteName="Home">
        <Root.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Root.Screen name="NotModal" component={NotModal} options={leftToRightAnimation} />
      </Root.Navigator>
 </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me. It seems like the cardStyleInterpolator function doesn't even get called when I do .navigate();

Comment: This worked perfect for me when using `Stack` navigator (not `NativeStackNavigator`), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the Navigator

**For Stack Navigator**

Use `gestureDirection: 'horizontal-inverted'`. An example:

```
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        gestureDirection: 'horizontal-inverted',
      }}
    >
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

**For Native Stack Navigator**

Use `animation: 'slide_from_right'`

```
<Stack.Navigator>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{animation: 'slide_from_right'}}
  />
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Profile"
    component={ProfileScreen}
    options={{animation: 'slide_from_right'}}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: `gestureDirection` is tied to how the screen can be closed by user swiping, not how the screen is animated in view. `slide_from_right` is Android online according to the docs (that may be fine depending on your use-case).

Answer (score 2):

**2023 solution**

You can define the direction by setting the "gestureDirection" option.

For Stack.Navigator:

```
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          gestureDirection: "horizontal-inverted"}
        }}
      ></Stack.Navigator>
```

For Stack.Screen:

```
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          gestureDirection: "horizontal-inverted"}
        }}
      ></Stack.Screen>
```

Comment: Easy, simple, perfect! Ty

Answer (score 1):

Set options

animation: 'slide_from_right'

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#options

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32279121)

Comment: `slide_from_<direction>` is Android only.

Answer (score 0):

for stack navigator, we can use CardStyleInterpolators. [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator#cardstyleinterpolators)

```
...    
options={{
     cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers did not work for me because `slide_from_right` only works on Android. I have a cross platform app. The way I solved this was by using route params in the Stack Navigator.

In my StackParamList, I set a mandatory `fromLocation` param.

```js
export type SomeStackParamList = {
 SomeStack: {
    randomField1: string;
    fromLocation: "home" | "chatscreen";
    newlyAddedNote?: string; // passing a string so it will register as changed every time
  };
}
```

Let's say I want navigations to the `chatScreen` to Slide in from left to right.

```
<SomeNavStack.Navigator // this is just to show the screen should be inside of a stack navigator
      initialRouteName="home"
      screenOptions={({ navigation, route }) => ({
        headerStyle: [
          styles.navHeaderStyle,
        ]
    ..... // you should copy the code below
 <PlaylistNavStack.Screen
        name="PlaylistContent"
        // @ts-ignore

        component={PlaylistContentScreen}
        options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
          gestureDirection:
            route.params.fromLocation === "home"
              ? "horizontal"
              : route.params.fromLocation === "chatScreen"
              ? "horizontal-inverted"
              : "horizontal", // I keep this third option in case I add more possible values in the future
          headerTitle: "Some Screen",
        })}
      />
```

Keep in mind, this example is on the options of a **screen** not a navigator. You can do the same think on the `screenOptions` of a navigator.